# Changing and saving background colors of listbox item

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, listbox

```
def change_color():
    colors = askcolor(title="Tkinter Color Chooser")
    index = listbox.curselection()
    if not index:
        return
    new = listbox.get(index)
    listbox.delete(index)
    listbox.insert(index, new)
    listbox.itemconfig(index, bg=colors[1])
    with open("bg_color2.txt", "w") as f:
        print("Writing color:", colors[1])
        f.write(colors[1])

def load_color2():
    index = listbox.curselection()
    if not index:
        return
    try:
        with open("bg_color2.txt", "r") as f:
            color = f.read()
            print("Reading color:", color)
            listbox.itemconfig(index, bg=color)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File bg_color2.txt not found")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error while loading color:", e)

load_color2()
```

I tried to change the bg color of listbox items with change_color and tried to load colors when I open it later.

I was expecting it to be working but I couldn't load colors and I don't see the problem.I can change colors.I actually did it before BUT accidentally deleted so It is possible.Please help if you can see the problem.You can change all the code except first 8 lines of change_color.You can change try and return too.

Comment: When `load_color2()` is executed during application start-up, there is no item selected in the listbox, so the file "bg_color2.txt" will not be read.

Comment: Oh yes,youre right but I dont think thats the only problem . Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: I think problem is with listbox.itemconfig(index, bg=color) this line in load color.But I dont know what to put instead of indx.